# In Ruby on Rails tests, how do I call from a ControllerTest a method defined inside a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, minitest

I have a test class called AdControllerTest, which I am using to test AdController.
From AdControllerTest, I'm trying to call a method defined in AdController, but I don't think I'm doing it right and I can't find the correct way to do this.

My test code looks like so

```
  test "pctr to final list is correct for pctr policy" do
    # Make a CTR list
    # Make a selectedAds list
    # Check that the CTR list reorders the selectedAds appropriately
    response = AdCampaign.search query: {
                              bool: {
                                must: [
                                  { match:  { target_gender: "F" },
                                      match:  { target_country: "KR" } } ]
                                  }}
    selectedAds = Array.new(NUMBEROFADS) {Hash.new} 
    for i in 1..NUMBEROFADS do
      selectedAds[i-1] = response.results.to_a[i-1]
    end

    testCTR = [0.032521635096847835, 0.03863127908388814, 0.007986670179316374]

    finalAds = AdController.pctrToAd(selectedAds: selectedAds, pctr: testCTR)

    # Manually order selectedAds by testCTR and compare
    comparisonAds = Array.new(NUMBEROFADS) {Hash.new}
    comparisonAds[0] = selectedAds[1]
    comparisonAds[1] = selectedAds[0]
    comparisonAds[2] = selectedAds[2]

    assert_equal(finalAds, comparisonAds)

  end
```

And within that code I'm trying to call `finalAds = AdController.pctrToAd(selectedAds: selectedAds, pctr: testCTR)`

The method pctrToAd is definitely defined in AdController.

But I get an error like so:

```
Error:
AdControllerTest#test_pctr_to_final_list_is_correct_for_pctr_policy:
NoMethodError: undefined method `pctrToAd' for AdController:Class
    test/controllers/ad_controller_test.rb:166:in `block in <class:AdControllerTest>'
```

Am I not supposed to call the method inside a controller that way? If not, how am I supposed to call it?

Comment: It's not incumbent to the context but you should try to keep the standard of using underscore_naming for your methods and variables if you are in ruby on rails. Consider adding rubocop to your bundle, and follow its recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

`AdController.pctrToAd` is calling a method on the AdController *class*. Presumably you want to call a method on an AdController *object*.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `pctrToAd' for AdController:Class
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Assuming this is AdControllerTest, [the controller object is available as `@controller`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#instance-variables-available).

```
finalAds = @controller.pctrToAd(selectedAds: selectedAds, pctr: testCTR)
```

Comment: Thank you. But now it says that it's an undefined method for nil:NilClass

Comment: I figured it out. @controller only becomes available after you call a "get" or others of the likes.

Comment: While this does fix the immediate problem in the long run its  still the wrong answer to the wrong question.

Comment: @max When answering an XY question, it's good to cover both the immediate and deep issues. We have them covered.

Answer (score 0):

## You don't.

The only methods inside your controller that should be public are the *actions* of the controller that are called by the router when it responds to HTTP requests.

Those are tested by sending HTTP requests with [integration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing) and [system tests](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing) to your application.

Writing controller tests is a highly flawed and outdated approach that is not recommended by the Rails core team. Isolating controllers is actually very hard as they are Rack applications and have a  hard dependency on an incoming request and the Rack middleware stack. Its also not a good idea as the extensive mocking required lets bugs slip through.

If you have a method that you want to call from the outside it does not belong in the controller. Put it in a model, service object or anywhere else where its actually easy to test it isolation. If you don't need to call/test it directly put it in a private method and test it indirectly.

Controllers have tons of responsibilities already. Don't turn them into the junk drawers of your application.

### What you do instead.

Extract the logic of the method that needs to be testable in isolation.  This can either be into the model layer or a Plain Old Ruby object such as a service object:

```
# app/services/ad_campains/frobnobizer_service.rb
module AdCampaigns
  class FrobnobizerService
    def initialize(selected_ads:, pctr:)
      @selected_ads = selected_ads
      @pctr = pctr 
    end

    def call
      # do something amazing
    end

    def self.call(selected_ads:, pctr:)
      new(...).run
    end
  end 
end
```

```
require "test_helper"

class AdCampaignsFrobnobizerServiceTest < Minitest::Test
  test "fobnobizes the whatchamacallits" do
    result = AdCampaigns::FrobnobizerService.call(
      selected_ads: [1,2,3], pctr: 'foobarbaz'
    )
    assert_equals(result[:foo], 'bar')
  end
end
```

When you compare this with a controller its extremely easy to test as it has very few dependencies and moving parts and only does one job.

You then test that the controller calls this component indirectly by sending a HTTP request:

```
class AdCampaignsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /ad_campigns/frobnobize
  def frobnobize
    @stuff = AdCampaigns::FrobnobizerService.call(
      selected_ads: [1,2,3], pctr: 'foobarbaz'
    )
    # do something with @stuff
  end
end
```

```
require "test_helper"

class AdCampaignsFlowTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "GET /ad_campigns/frobnobize" do
    get '/ad_campigns/frobnobize'
    # test that the controller called the service by
    # writing assertions/refutions about the headers
    # response body or potential side effects.
  end
end
```

In some cases you might want to use spies/mocks to ensure that the controller calls the collaborator as expected instead of testing the outcome.

Comment: I guess then the problem is I don't know where I should put a test that tests a specific portion of the logic that the controller does.

Comment: Not really. If you want to test a specific portion of what your controller does in isolation then thats actually telling you that the code does not belong in the controller. I can tell from just the name that it most definately doesn't.

Comment: Testing the normal logic of your controllers (the actions) is done via integration and system tests. Everything else that doesn't have a route attached to it should be a private method.

Comment: that doesn't make sense to me... How is it possible you would never want to test just a specific part of the controller?

Comment: Because you don't use the controller as a junk drawer for all your miscellaneus junk. I feel like we are stuck in a loop here. Extract this into a separate object and write a test for it. Then you will test that the controller calls it correctly through an integration test of the action that depends on that logic.

Comment: Ok, I guess the missing link I have here is I don't know how to write a test for a separate object that's not a controller

Comment: This sounds kind of like you approached learning testing backwards. Typically you want to learn how to test plain old ruby objects first as that carries over to every other kind of testing. https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-minitest